# Use Partial file name on import from SharePoint with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I'm trying to open, and import values to a workbook from another workbook. Both files are in SharePoint and in the same directory.

It works as long as the target file has a specific name. But the file will have a variable start and ending in the name. 5 varying numbers + name + varying date (72262-Faktureringsplan-2018-11-16).

I've tried using * but it seems it doesn't work with SharePoint. How can I use some kind of "wildcards" for accessing files names in SharePoint?

This is the part of the code that will load the file:

```
Sub faktureringsplan()

Dim FileName As String
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\72262-Faktureringsplan-2018-11-16.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B10:B31").Value = wb.Sheets(1).Range("B2:B23").Value
MsgBox ("Ferdig")
wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

This code is trying to look for very specific filename with '\72262-Faktureringsplan-2018-11-16.xlsx'
on line:

```
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\72262-Faktureringsplan-2018-11-16.xlsx"
```

The way wildcard("*") works, is that it replaces the part you want to match with anything. So a simple change from the above to

```
"\72262-Faktureringsplan-*.xlsx"
```

would return filename that has any date starting with '72262-Faktureringsplan' in your case.

You could also make use of VBA's date function to find a matching filedate that has the same date as today's date.

```
Format(date, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

would return today's date in the format "2018-11-16" (date of this reply).

Essentially, you can do something like this:

```
FileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*-Faktureringsplan-" & Format(date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"
```

This would match the following: ANYTHING-Faktureringsplan-TODAY'S_DATE.xlsx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the wildcard. It didnt work. I suspect its because the path is an internet adress. (SharePoint) Maybe it needs something more?

Comment: What happens when i use the * for eksample at the end, is that the workbook tries to open an non existing workbook with the name «72262-Faktureringsplan-*». So i get an empty weird sheet with an error.

Comment: About the date, i thought of it too. But it would create some inconvenience, as the operation could only be made same day as the target workbook was created.

Comment: To be more specific this is the code i tried.  "\*-Faktureringsplan-*" & ".xlsx"

Comment: Sorry, I am not that familiar with sharepoint, but here is a post https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74386/wildcard-search-in-a-sharepoint-list. It is saying we can't do suffix matching, so we are only limited to a search like this "72262-Faktureringsplan-*.xlsx"

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the tip! If i cant find the solution i guess ill have to try to do something about the file name the target workbook gets when exported in Sharepoint.